# Was there a Fantasy Battle equivalent to Lucius the Eternal?

Tags: character-identification, warhammer-fantasy

I love the character Lucius the Eternal from Warhammer 40K but I am finding myself thinking I could remember that there was a fantasy battle equivalent back in 4th or 5th edition.

A slaanesh champion swordsman who had armour that contained the souls of those he had killed, if he was killed then he came back in their body. However hunting online I can't find this which makes me wonder if my memory is playing tricks.